# why rabbitmq fanout exchange only one subscribe can be received message？

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I created a rebbitmq fanout exchange example integration spring,but just only one subscribe can received message ,why？flowing is my configuration:
publish configuration

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" username="dev" password="dev" host="localhost" />

<rabbit:template id="template" connection-factory="connectionFactory" reply-timeout="2000"   exchange="2remoting.exchange" />

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

<rabbit:queue name="remoting.queue1" />


<rabbit:fanout-exchange name="2remoting.exchange" >
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="remoting.queue1"/>
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:fanout-exchange>
```

subscribe configuration

```
<bean id="service" class="com.hzins.bsp.dev.TestServiceImpl" />

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" username="dev" password="dev" host="localhost" />

<rabbit:template id="template" connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

<rabbit:queue name="remoting.queue1" />

<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory">
    <rabbit:listener ref="listener" queue-names="remoting.queue1" />
    <rabbit:listener ref="listener" queue-names="remoting.queue1" />
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you misunderstood the `fanout exchange` definition. It puts the message to **all** binded queues., but not to subscribes for those queues.

It does not have value how much subscribers (listeners) you have for the same queue. They are just concurrent consumers and only the one of them will receive a message from the queue.

Please, read more RabbitMQ docs.